# Pac4J with OKTA and springboot

Tags: okta, pac4j, okta-signin-widget

im trying to adapt the very nice sample [spring-webmvc-pac4j-boot-demo](https://github.com/pac4j/spring-webmvc-pac4j-boot-demo).
i made some minor change to this working exemple with PAC4J and Spring MVC to request OKTA hosted login page with some OIDCclient
i was exepecting to be redirected to the okta login page and after successful login being granted to the requested page. But i receive an HTTP 400 instead

My parameters at the okta part are:

```
Sign-in redirect URIs  = http://localhost:8080/oidc
Sign-out redirect URIs = http://localhost:8080
Initiate login URI = http://localhost:8080/callback
```

at the application code (Pac4jConfig.java):
i created an Oidc config:

```
     final OidcConfiguration oidcConfiguration = new OidcConfiguration();
     oidcConfiguration.setClientId("my client ID");
     oidcConfiguration.setSecret("big big secret");
     oidcConfiguration.setDiscoveryURI("https://myforeverhostatokta.okta.com/oauth2/default/.well-known/openid-configuration");
    final OidcClient oidcClient = new OidcClient(oidcConfiguration);
    oidcClient.setCallbackUrl("http://localhost:8080/callback");
...

and i created an interceptor (SecurityConfig.java):
...
    registry.addInterceptor(buildInterceptor("OidcClient")).addPathPatterns("/oidc/*");
```

when i run the modified sample and request localhost:8080/oidc, im redirected to my OKTA server with an HTTP 400 error page claiming that my client application should have some redirect uri set in it.
Im sticked with that because i dont know where the Hell should i set this redirect uri in my pac4j configuration.
Any Help or hinsights for that problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [Build a Java REST API with Java EE and OIDC](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/09/12/secure-java-ee-rest-api) tutorial on the Okta developer blog that should help. Specifically, the [Use Pac4j to Lock Down Your Java REST API](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/09/12/secure-java-ee-rest-api#use-pac4j-to-lock-down-your-java-rest-api) section.

You could also clone the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/oktadev/okta-java-ee-rest-api-example/tree/pac4j) and look at the code:

```
git clone -b pac4j https://github.com/oktadev/okta-java-ee-rest-api-example.git
```